# Tikz equivalent for axisratio

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-external

I want to externalise all my tikz figures. I currently create them by

```
\begin{filecontents}{images/spring.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %tikz picture code
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, axisratio=3]{images/spring.tikz} 
   }
\end{figure}
```

But for some reason I can't get `\includegraphics` to work with external tikz. That is why I want to create my tikz with:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      %tikz code
      \begin{tikzpicture}
   }
\end{figure}
```

However I have a lot of figures and don't want to manually adjust the plots. That's why I'd like to use the `axisratio` (and `\linewidth`) function of `\includegraphics`. Is there such a equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure. For `\inlinegraphics`, do you mean `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Hi @Ignasi, yes I do. Sorry typo! I've edited the questoin

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do but I think you need to look at [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) and [`tikzscale`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale).